# Displaying SQLite data within a RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have a RecyclerView that displays a 2 pieces of text that the user inputs. I am using an SQL database to store these inputs, then permanently display them onto the RecyclerView. The issue is that it it doesn't permanently remain within the recyclerview. When I click the recyclerview, it takes me to another activity as desired; but when I go back the entire database disappears and the recyclerview is empty.

Any idea why this happens and how to fix it? How do I get the sql database to permanently display on the recyclerview?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
public class ExerciseRoutine extends Fragment implements 
ExerciseRoutine_Dialog.RoutineDialogListener{

private ArrayList<ExerciseRoutine_Information> Routine_information = new ArrayList<>();

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

@Override
public void sendInput(String name, String split) {
 //Receives the user input from a dialogfragment and stores it into Arraylist
    Routine_information.add(new ExerciseRoutine_Information(name, split));

    adapter = new ExerciseRoutineAdapter(getContext(), Routine_information);

//AsynTask that adds the user input into the sql database
    BackendTask_Eroutine backendTask_add = new BackendTask_Eroutine(getContext());
    backendTask_add.execute("add_eRoutine", name, split);

    adapter.notifyItemInserted(Routine_information.size());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.exercise_routine_fragment, container, 
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    //AsyncTask that displays user inputs in recyclerview
    BackendTask_Eroutine backendTask_display = new BackendTask_Eroutine(getContext());
    Routine_information = backendTask_display.getRoutineList();
    backendTask_display.execute("display_eRoutine");

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.ExerciseRoutine_Recycler);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    adapter = new ExerciseRoutineAdapter(getContext(), Routine_information);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    return view;
}
```

AsychTask: Responsible for both adding inputs and displaying them

```
 public class BackendTask_Eroutine extends AsyncTask<String, 
 ExerciseRoutine_Information, String> {

private Context mContext;

private ArrayList<ExerciseRoutine_Information> eRoutineData = new ArrayList<>();

public BackendTask_Eroutine(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}

public ArrayList<ExerciseRoutine_Information> getRoutineList() {
    return eRoutineData;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

    ExerciseRoutine_DBHandler dbHandler = new ExerciseRoutine_DBHandler(mContext);

    String method = strings[0];

    if(method.equals("add_eRoutine")){
        String name = strings[1];
        String split = strings[2];

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getWritableDatabase();
        dbHandler.insertData(db, name, split);

        return "One Row Inserted...";
    }

    if(method.equals("display_eRoutine")){

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHandler.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = dbHandler.getData(db);

        String name, split;

        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ExerciseRoutine_DBHandler.NAME));
            split = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ExerciseRoutine_DBHandler.SPLIT));

            ExerciseRoutine_Information info = new ExerciseRoutine_Information(name, split);

            publishProgress(info);
        }
        return "Display eRoutine";
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(ExerciseRoutine_Information... values) {
    eRoutineData.add(values[0]);
}
```